# How to find out the sub array where any two elements sum > k?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

Last weekend I was asked this question in an interview. There is an array of positive numbers. From this array ,  you need to find out the subset. From this subset, you should be able to pick up any two numbers and their sum would always be greater than k. k is an user inputted value.

I was able to solve this question in two passes. In the first pass, I will pick up all the items greater than k and put them in the sub array. While doing so,  I will find out the minimum value from this subset.

In the next pass,I will sort the array in descending order. After that I will keep adding numbers to the subset by summing them up with the minimum number in the subset.

The solution mentions above solves the problem. However the time complexity would be O(n + nlogn). However the interviewer wanted it to be O(n). Needless to say I was not able to do that. Please help me with the algorithm. I did try to search the internet. However I could not find anything with o(n) time complexity.

Comment: Just a note: O(n + nlogn) = O(nlogn). Only the biggest term is relevant to big-O.

Comment: Why do you sort the array? It doesn't look like you are using the sorted property anywhere in your algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add all the numbers greater than `k/2` to the subset (keep track of the minimum).
- Go through the array again and add any number greater than `k-minimum of subset` to the subset. Stop after we added 1.

  If this is part of the requirements, you can look for the biggest one.

This runs in `O(n)`.

The reasoning here is as follows:

- Any 2 elements `> k/2` will add up to more than `k`.
- If one element is `<= k/2`, the other element will need to be `> k/2` to add up to at least `k`, so there can't be more than one element `<= k/2` (since if there were 2, those 2 won't add up to more than `k`).

An example of this is `k = 10, array = [3,4,8,9,10]`, with the output being `[3,8,9,10]` or `[4,8,9,10]`. `8,9,10` will get added in the first step, then we'll add `3` or `4` in the second step.

---

Technical note: "Subset" implies unique elements. We can use a hash table to get *expected* (but not guaranteed) `O(n)` complexity. If it's instead a "subsequence" (not unique elements), we can just add them to an array or linked-list for `O(n)` complexity.

Comment: greater than or equal ===> greater than.

Comment: See if you read this, this looks so simple! But in the interview, I was struggling to even think like this. Thanks a lot for such a quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to solve it with complexity O(n). With a single loop on the array, take only numbers that are greater than k/2.
A simple algorithm would look like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    if(arr[i] > k/2.0){
         add arr[i] to the subset
    }
}
```

Comment: We sometimes need to add numbers <= k/2, e.g. `k = 10, array = [4,8,9,10], output = [4,8,9,10]`.